# How to plot a variability chart in MATLAB for indexed columns (also known as grouped columns)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is a common plot type in Origin or JMP but somehow I couldn't find the reference to generate the plot in MATLAB.
I need to generate this plot in a script so I need to this in MATLAB now.
I am interested in displaying the indexed columns like the charts below:
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXZEF.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjcI3.jpg)

Tried known Matlab plotting references, no luck

Comment: Are you looking for [`boxchart`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boxchart.html) ?

Comment: More than box chart I am looking for the ability to add multiple axes just like the ones in the example

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60857-how-to-create-variability-charts This seems to be a little more in the direction you are looking for.

Comment: For multiple axes, see [`tiledlayout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html)